# Is it normal for keys in a hashtable to sometimes collide with themselves?

Tags: java, hashtable

This my 2nd  time on Stack Overflow so please tell me if I am missing any details and sorry if  my question  is not that properly formatted, I'm not used this site constantly.

My question is: When I run my code it's supposed to print back as an output:

- the percentage of the hash-table that is filled,
- the total accumulated collisions,
- the total number of collisions, and
- the name of keys that are being collided with when inserting keys into the hash-table.

All of which comes out fine except when printing out the names of the keys that are being collided with, sometimes it prints out the same name of the key being inserted, and I am not sure if that's supposed to happen in a hash-table or not?

```
/** Container class for a key-value pair */

   class KVpair<Key, E> {
   private Key k;
   private E e;

  /** Constructors */
  KVpair()
    { k = null; e = null; }
  KVpair(Key kval, E eval)
    { k = kval; e = eval; }

  /** Data member access functions */
  public Key key() { return k; }
  public E value() { return e; }
 }


public class HashTable<Key extends Comparable<? super Key>, E> {

private int M;
private KVpair<Key, E>[] HT;
private int collisionSum = 0;

private int h(Key key) {
    HashFunction hf = new HashFunction();
    return hf.sfold((String) key, M);
}

private int p(Key key, int slot) {
    return slot;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Generic array allocation
HashTable(int m) {
    M = m;
    HT = (KVpair<Key, E>[]) new KVpair[M];
}

/** Insert record r with key k into HT */
void hashInsert(Key k, E r) {
    int home; // Home position for r
    int pos = home = h(k); // Initial position
    int AccumulatedSum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; HT[pos] != null; i++) {
        collisionSum++;
        AccumulatedSum++;
        if (HT[pos].key().compareTo(k) != 0 )
            System.out.println("Collided with key " + HT[pos].key());
        pos = (home + p(k, i)) % M; // Next probe slot
        assert HT[pos].key().compareTo(k) != 0 : "Duplicates not allowed";
    }
    HT[pos] = new KVpair<Key, E>(k, r); // Insert R
    System.out.printf("Accumulated collisions: %d\n", AccumulatedSum);
    System.out.printf("Total number of  Collisions %d\n", collisionSum);
}

/** Search in hash table HT for the record with key k */
E hashSearch(Key k) {
    int home; // Home position for k
    int pos = home = h(k); // Initial position
    for (int i = 1; (HT[pos] != null) && (HT[pos].key().compareTo(k) != 0); i++) {
        pos = (home + p(k, i)) % M; // Next probe position
        if (i == M) {
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println(pos);
    }

    return HT[pos].value(); // Found it
}

}


import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

  // This is the hashFunction that will be used in the hashtable
  // for linear probing of indexes when collisions happen. 
   //where s is the String key being passed and M is the size of the hashTable 

    public class HashFunction
{

     int sfold(String s, int M) {

     int intLength = s.length() / 4;
     int sum = 0;
     for (int j = 0; j < intLength; j++) {
       char c[] = s.substring(j*4,(j*4)+4).toCharArray();
    int mult = 1;
    for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
        sum += c[k] * mult;
        mult *= 256;
      }
  }
     char c[] = s.substring(intLength * 4).toCharArray();
     int mult = 1;
     for (int k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
        sum += c[k] * mult;
        mult *= 256;
  }
    return(Math.abs(sum) % M);
  }
    int h(String x, int M) {
    char ch[];
    ch = x.toCharArray();
    int xlength = x.length(); 
    int i, sum;
    for (sum=0, i=0; i < xlength; i++)
         sum += ch[i];
    return sum % M;
}
   int h(int x) {
    return(x % 16);
  }

}


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class randHashTableDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int htLength = 128; // HashTable Size
        HashTable<String, String> hashT = new HashTable<>(htLength);
        HashTable<String, String> hashT2= new HashTable<>(htLength);
        fillHashTable(hashT, htLength, 0.4);
        fillHashTable(hashT2, htLength, 0.6);

    }

    // Generates a String array filled with words of 8 letters in length with no
    // duplicates
    static String[] randomWordGen(int wordCount) {
        int wordLength = 8;
        String[] words = new String[wordCount];
        Arrays.fill(words, "");
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
            String s = "";
            for (int t = 0; t < wordLength; t++) {
                char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 65);
                s += c;
            }
            if (Arrays.asList(words).contains(s)) {
                i--;
                continue;
            }
            words[i] += s;
        }
        return words;
    }

    // Creates the HashTable and Fills it with indexes until it reaches the
    // Percent specified
    static void fillHashTable(HashTable<String, String> h, int size, double fillPercentage ) {
        int indexes = (int) Math.ceil( size * fillPercentage);
        String[] words = randomWordGen(indexes);
        System.out.println("\n\n------Filling HashTable------");
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes; i++) {
            h.hashInsert(words[i], words[i]);
            System.out.printf("\nInserting Word: %s , FillPercentage: %.2f\n", words[i], ((i+1d) /size) * 100);
        }

    }

}
```

Example output of where the problem occurs (output is actually longer than this):

```
------Filling HashTable------
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 0

Inserting Word: KPUWLEYG , FillPercentage: 0.78
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 0

Inserting Word: CVJLHZTS , FillPercentage: 1.56
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 0

Inserting Word: PHTMMRDF , FillPercentage: 2.34
Collided with key PHTMMRDF
Accumulated collisions: 1
Total number of  Collisions 1

Inserting Word: LBHTQOZT , FillPercentage: 3.13
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 1

Inserting Word: JJIRZFEU , FillPercentage: 3.91
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 1

Inserting Word: ETWYECDW , FillPercentage: 4.69
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 1

Inserting Word: PEKVFYWK , FillPercentage: 5.47
Collided with key PHTMMRDF
Collided with key LBHTQOZT
Accumulated collisions: 2
Total number of  Collisions 3

Inserting Word: LSRKQZWI , FillPercentage: 6.25
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 3

Inserting Word: QVVHNKKY , FillPercentage: 7.03
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 3

Inserting Word: AWNKDWPU , FillPercentage: 7.81
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 3

Inserting Word: BCLQXGGZ , FillPercentage: 8.59
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 3

Inserting Word: NWCLTWVW , FillPercentage: 9.38
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 3

Inserting Word: EZMHLCRT , FillPercentage: 10.16
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 3

Inserting Word: AKOREOMM , FillPercentage: 10.94
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 3

Inserting Word: TFFDJHDM , FillPercentage: 11.72
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 3

Inserting Word: CVLWLOMC , FillPercentage: 12.50
Collided with key PEKVFYWK
Accumulated collisions: 1
Total number of  Collisions 4

Inserting Word: JHTDLBBU , FillPercentage: 13.28
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 4

Inserting Word: DSQRNEFA , FillPercentage: 14.06
Accumulated collisions: 0
Total number of  Collisions 4

Inserting Word: FOBTANHC , FillPercentage: 14.84
Collided with key QVVHNKKY
Collided with key TFFDJHDM
Collided with key PHTMMRDF
Collided with key LBHTQOZT
Collided with key LSRKQZWI
Collided with key BCLQXGGZ
Accumulated collisions: 6
Total number of  Collisions 10

Inserting Word: MLJVRHMQ , FillPercentage: 15.63
Collided with key MLJVRHMQ
Accumulated collisions: 1
Total number of  Collisions 11
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - clearly a given key will "collide" with itself (given that a hash function is deterministic).

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, then yes. Because of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: What I am asking is  when inserting a key into a hashtable is it normal for the key to collide with itself

Answer (score 1):

```
is it normal for the key to collide with itself
```

Yes, Hash collision is normal and perhaps practically not avoidable when hashing a random large set of keys. A proof could be - hashcode is of `integer` type with the max value of `(2^32)-1`. However, the hash table implementations like HashMap/Hashtable follow collision resolution strategy to handle such events. The strategy used here is called separate chaining where a bucket is created and has some sort of list of entries with the same index. If you google with "HashMap intenal implementation", you can find more details.

Basically, if we need to retrieve value object in case of collision, a call to hashCode() method will retrieve bucket and traverse thought list by comparing keys in each entries using keys.equals() until it matches. Thus there is a common saying in Java "Override hashcode when you override equals" because two unequal objects may return the same hashcode but When two objects are equal by equals(), they must have the same hashcode.